# How does one configure the function called on an orgmode link such as file:~/Dropbox/ToProcess?

Tags: org-mode, dired

I am using `Org mode` version 9.3  under `GNU Emacs` 27.1 (under Linux Debian).
Typing enter on links such as `file:~/Dropbox/ToProcess/` used to open the directory in `dired-mode`:
I have a bunch of text automatisations based on this behavior.

At some point, emacs' behavior changed, nothing happening when selecting such link:
It seems that it generates the message `Running less /home/jbarbay/Dropbox/ToProcess/...done`.
I searched for an instance of `less` in my orgmode configuration file in particular and in all my  emacs configuration files with no success.
(Selecting links to specific sections in other orgmode files does work as intended.)

Typing enter on such links (correctly) calls the function 'org-open-at-point', which prints the same message when called directly.
`org-open-at-point` 's documentation describes its behavior for such "syntactically correct links" relatively vaguely:

```
 On top of syntactically correct links, this function also tries
 to open links and time-stamps in comments, node properties, and
 keywords if point is on something looking like a timestamp or
 a link.
```

Does any knows what could have changed this behavior and how to return to the previous one, opening a folder into 'dired-mode'?

Comment: Do `C-h v org-file-apps` to read the doc string of the variable and then do the same for the variable that is appropriate for you system: `org-file-apps-macos`, `org-file-apps-windowsnt` or `org-file-apps-gnu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `org-file-apps` controls which app is started on which file.
Adding the following to one's configuration reset emacs to open a directory in 'dired-mode':

```
  (setq org-file-apps
               (append '(
                         (directory . emacs)
                         ) org-file-apps ))
```

Thanks to @NickD for the pointer to the variable `org-file-apps` !

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)  - look also at the link [to accept an answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) that has a nice summary of what to do in various cases.